# How to click controls inside Popup with StaysOpen as False

Tags: wpf

I have a `Popup` with a `ListView` inside. I'd like to set `StaysOpen` as False so that it properly closes when I click away from the popup. However, this means that all mouse events are intercepted. As such, I don't get any mouse events inside my ListView.

Here's my current setup. I've removed all styling to make it easier to see what's going on.

```
 <Popup Name="puSearchResults" StaysOpen="False"
            AllowsTransparency="True"
            LostFocus="puSearchResults_LostFocus" 
            LostKeyboardFocus="puSearchResults_LostKeyboardFocus" 
            LostMouseCapture="puSearchResults_LostMouseCapture" >
   <ListView Name="lvSearchResults" 
             MouseLeftButtonDown="lbSearchResults_MouseLeftButtonDown"
             SelectionChanged="lvSearchResults_SelectionChanged"/>
</Popup>
```

In this case, `MouseLeftButtonDown` only works if I set `StaysOpen` to True, but then the `Popup` doesn't disappear if I click away.

Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I would add mouse events to the ListView or to the objects in your ListView's data templete.

Then you could do this:

```
private void lvSearchResults_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  puSearchResults.StaysOpen = true;
}

private void lvSearchResults_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  puSearchResults.StaysOpen = false;
}
```

**EDIT**

Similar question that should help: [Close Wpf Popup On click of item of its own control template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470490/close-wpf-popup-on-click-of-item-of-its-own-control-template)

Comment: When I set StaysOpen to true, it automatically sets IsOpen to false, and as such I have to set it back to true to see the Popup. As a result you can see the popup flickering.

Comment: Also, as you hover on the ListView, the Popup thinks you're not longer inside the Popup.